# Heston model with Jumps

Tags: stochastic-volatility, heston

Heston model can be used to find prices of options under stochastic volatility. How do I include jumps in the model, so that I end up with a different stochastic volatility curve? References to literature would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

Try [this](http://elis.sigmath.es.osaka-u.ac.jp/research/Heston-original.pdf) and [this](https://phps.portals.mbs.ac.uk/Portals/49/docs/20110627_SV_Heston.pdf).

But if you don't know the black-scholes basics well consider to read the book "Paul Wilmott in Quantitative Finance" before to go to Stochastic Volatility models and models with jumps.

Answer (score 1):

don't know If I understand well your question, but If you want to have a rather complete perspective about the affine class of models (to which Heston's model belongs), you better study [Duffie et al. (2000)](http://darrellduffie-com.gowest1.gowesthosting.com/uploads/pubs/DuffiePanSingleton2000.pdf). In this very important contribution you'll find many examples of jump specifications

Answer (score 0):

You can start with *[Wilmott](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470319585)*:

$dS_t = \mu S_t dt +\sigma S_t dZ_t + (J-1)S_t dq_t$

where the Poisson Process

\begin{equation}
  dq_t =\begin{cases}
    0, & \text{with prob $1-\lambda(t)dt$}\\
    1, & \text{with prob $\lambda(t)dt$}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Also assume that jump arrival rate $\lambda(t)$ is independent of stock price

Assuming a known jump size $J$ is simple but somewhat unrealistic, one can assume some distribution of jump size. For example, Merton's jump diffusion models assumes $J$ to be lognormally distributed.

Note however, that in the case of random jump size, there's no replicating portfolio so there is no self-financing hedge.